# React final form with Material UI Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, selectlist, react-final-form

I have an issue when using React final-form with Material UI Select. That is when the Select list items change and the new lists do not include the previously selected value, but the form value still keeps that selected value which should be cleared.

For example:
I have the Select component name="test" with Select list items:

```
listItems = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Then I select "3" value. The form value with property "test" was assigned to "3".

After that, the list items have changed.

```
listItems = ["1", "4", "5", "7"]
```

The new list does not include "3" value but my form value still keep "3" value in "test" property.

Are there any ways to clear that value when select list change and the new list does not include that value anymore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on where the list change is coming from. A sandbox would really help here.

Anywhere inside your form, [you have access to the Final Form `form` API](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#form-formapi) to call `form.change('test', undefined)` imperatively. Perhaps you could do that when your list changes?

Comment: Erik R, thanks for your answer. It sounds good, my select list change when the value of other select change, imagine 2 select box (1 for region, 1 for country), country list change when region selected change. So as your suggestion, I will put the form.change func on the onChange event of Region select list force clear the value of country when region changed